# How do I insert a delay or make code Wait Until said action is done?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delay

```
  public Rigidbody rb;
        public GameObject gObject;
        public bool TouchGround;
     
        
        
        void OnBecameInvisible()
        {
           //Add a delay here that activateson TouchGround = True
       FindObjectOfType<CameraMovement>().Seen("Testing");
        }
```

How do I insert a delay or make code  Wait Until said action is done?

Comment: Take a look at coroutines. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public Rigidbody rb;
    public GameObject gObject;
    public bool TouchGround;

    void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitCoroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator WaitCoroutine()
    {
        while (TouchGround)
        {
            // Waits until TouchGround is false and then continues
            yield return null;
        }

        FindObjectOfType<CameraMovement>().Seen("Testing");
    }
```

Just add a `!` in front of the TouchGround if you want to wait until the bool is `true`.